# Open bookmarks via hotkeys in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, internet, browser, bookmarks

Is it possible open/launch my bookmarks in Firefox via hotkeys?

If so, how?

I want something that will allow me to specify the hotkey(s).

I don't want another speed dial clone.

Answer (score 0):

- Sidebar: `<Ctrl>+B`
- Manager: `<Ctrl>+<Shift>+B`

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on your bookmark and click "Properties", you can set a keyword for each bookmark. Then just type the keyword into the address bar and it will automatically go to the bookmark.

For more efficiency, use ALT+D or CTRL+L shortcuts to focus to the address bar and then type in the keyword.